# Favorite Questions

Tags: discussion, support

Once you have made a question one of your favorites, how do you get back to it?  I noticed that when you click "Questions" you go a new page with categories "newest," "faq," "votes, "active," and "unanswered."  Shouldn't there be a "favorites" category too?  And, wouldn't in be cool to be able to see a list of favorite questions ordered by the number of people for whom they were favorites?

The list of favorite questions would be important for users, Wolfram, indeed all mankind.

Comment: Dear George, looking at your profile, it seems that you might have some interesting insights to add as an answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8267/8). Please feel free to do so when you have time. I know I'd be interested to read about your experiences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once you have made a question one of your favorites, how do you get back to it?

That would be [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2308?tab=favorites), which is accessible from [your profile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2308) under the "favorites" tab.

Answer (score 8):

You don't even have to go to another page as mentioned in J.M.'s answer. Just float your mouse pointer over your name at the top of the page. In the drop down window that appears click on the word "Favorites".